# Cannot connect to WiFi network on Windows 8 / 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-configuration

I see about 12 other WiFi networks in the WiFi list displayed by Windows and can even connect to them (one of them I know), so WiFi is basically working.

However, I cannot find the network I usually connect to after the AP was rebooted.

I tried to remove the existing WiFi in the Modern/Metro UI listing known WiFis and then tried to manually reconnect to it according to [this guide](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-connect-hidden-wireless-networks-windows-8), including the option to connect even when the AP does not broadcast its SSID, but it does not appear to do anything.

Rebooting the computer or disabling and reenabling the network adapter did not change anything.

What is wrong here?
Why can't I see my network but other WiFis?
Why can't I connect to this particular network but to others?

The WiFi is using WPA2 Enterprise, and both an OS X and an iOS device *can* see it and connect to it without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the AP rebooted into [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode), preventing Windows computers from connecting to it.

Microsoft has an [article mentioning monitor mode preventing successful connections](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/cant-find-wireless-network) but it was not clearly stated that this refers to the AP.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some AP can self-reset and start broadcasting their DEFAULT (out-of-the-box) open SSID (Linksys etc)...which unfortunately you can't connect to.

Try confirm that's not your case. Check for any open wireless network amongst those broadcasting... You might need to reconfigure the AP once again.

Try reboot the AP. This is also a likely solution to your  issue. Just do a power cycle.(pull the power cord for about 10secs and plug back).

Comment: Thanks for your input, but apparently it was just monitor mode being enabled.